# ASP.NET MVC 3 FilterAttribute - setting a variable that will be accessible in the Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, .net-4.0, controller, razor, actionfilterattribute

In a FilterAttribute I am making in MVC3, I want to set a variable that will be accessible inside my Controller.  How can I do this?  Is it possible?  Thank you.

Comment: You mean like having an attribute on a controller that you can set?

Comment: Can you give a little more context...? You might need a custom model binder or something else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could put your value in the `Items` collection of the `HttpContext` object.